# EditText setEnabled() not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've two EditText fields and I want to enable the second EditText only after user inputs some value in first EditText. I tried the following but it isn't giving expected results. The second editText remains disabled even when the user inputs the value in the first.

```
String et1Value = et1.getText().toString();
if(!et1Value.equals("")){
et2.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: You have assigned setEnabled as false. Please make it as true for the et2.

Comment: Where is this code called...on any specific event?

Comment: replace et2.setEnabled(false); with et1.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Use a `TextWatcher` on the first `EditText`.

Comment: Use `TextChangeListener` . And change `false` to **true** . Try the code i hade explained below\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Define this under your edittext in onCreate**

try the following code with text change listener

```
  et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft )                                                                          
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
         String et1Value = et1.getText().toString();
         if(!et1Value.equals("")){
         et2.setEnabled(true);
        }
        }
    });
```